# Inserting into table from json and another different table

Tags: sql, json, insert

I'm trying to insert values that are from two different tables. I have 3 values that are from a JSON text and the item_id from another table. The code below is what I've got so far however I'm stuck on doing this.

```
INSERT INTO NETWORK (TBL1.MAC_ADDR, TBL1.TYPE, TBL1.IP_ADDRESS, TBL2.ITEM_ID) 
            (SELECT TBL1.MAC_ADDR, TBL1.TYPE, TBL1.IP_ADDRESS
                FROM OPENJSON(@JSON_TEXT, '$.networks') 
                WITH (MAC_ADDR VARCHAR(50) '$.MAC_ADDRESS'
                ,TYPE VARCHAR(50) '$.NTYPE'
                ,IP_ADDRESS VARCHAR(50) '$.IP_ADDRESS') AS TBL1,
                (SELECT ID FROM ITEM WHERE OCS_ID = JSON_VALUE(@JSON_TEXT,'$.OCS_ID')) AS TBL2)
```

Is there a way of doing this?